# How to restore a database from a backup in installshield

Tags: sql-server, backup, installshield, database-restore

I'm using MSI Project with InstallShield 2010.

I have a .bak file, a backup of a SQL database (I am using SQL Server 2008 R2). How can I restore it using InstallShield?

I was looking in SQL Scripts tab and I didn't find anything about restoring backups.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Could you run you backup script as an SSIS package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

say suppose you have xyz.bak as a bakup and you want to restore it on to your sqlserver 2008r2 try running following query in ssms

```
Restore database DatabaseName from disk='path of your bak file'
```

this will restore your database.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you could use a SQL script to restore the .BAK file but this isn't really the best practice.  What you are supposed to do is "script out" the database into one or many SQL files and execute those files to create your database during the install.

Comment: why isn't the best practice to restore .bak?

Answer (score 0):

In hopes of getting an answer to this thread's original question, let's say that building up the database via the "script out" approach would take way too long to perform at install-time.

Scripted out, the database I am working with takes ~90 min to get built up. Restoring a 1.6 GB compressed .bak takes ~90 sec.

I am interested in restoring a .bak as part of my IS2010 msi project. Currently CAs are used but a more elegant solution (especially one that can provide progress back to the user) would be more ideal.

Comment: Although you are unable to add comments, answers should really contain an answer to the question.